# sqlalchemy does not initialize the database

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have created a models.py file describing my schema.  I am using the code below to create the DB and initialize it with the model.py schema.  When I call the create_app function a new sqlite file gets create but it is empty.  It is not picking up the schema from my models.py file.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy_utils.functions import database_exists

db = SQLAlchemy()
DB_NAME = "database.db"


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = f'sqlite:///{DB_NAME}'

    if not database_exists(app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']):
        db.init_app(app)
        db.create_all(app=app)
        print(f'Created Database Successfully!!')

    return app
```

models.py

```
from .main import db
from flask_login import UserMixin
from sqlalchemy.sql import func

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(150), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(150))
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(150))
```

Comment: You need to import the models first

Answer (score 0):

happened to me with missing **init**.py file in the package, maybe thats the case

Answer (score 0):

After I imported the models file first, the DB was created sucessfully.